# Python/Pandas - Adding a hourly column with floats (ex 3.30) to time column (ex 7:00am)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time

I have a dataset with two columns that I want to combine, one has floats which represent hours/mins, and the other has a start time such as 7:00am.  I also pulled the data from regular expressions, so the hours column has a tab space indicator such as \t:

```
Hours - Start Time
\t3.30    7:00am
\t1.0     7:00am
\t2.30    7:30am
```

I am attempting to make a third column where the floats are added in hour/min format to create new times:

```
Desired Output:

Hours - Start Time - New Time
\t3.30     7:00am     10:30am    
\t1.0      7:00am      8:00am
\t2.30     7:30am     10:00am
```

How would I go about doing this?  I tried a few methods such as converting the Hours column to Hours/Mins with DateTime, and Time Delta, but am running into issues, I recongize it could be due to the tabular spaces (\t).  Upon trying to remove those with re, I also got stuck.  Appreciate any who can assist.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import dateutil
import pandas as pd
df['Hours'] = df.Hours.replace(r'.*(\d+)\.(\d+)', r'\1:\2', regex=True)
df['New Time'] = df.apply(lambda x: dateutil.parser.parse(x['Start Time']) + datetime.timedelta(hours=int(x.Hours.split(':')[0]), minutes=int(x.Hours.split(':')[1])), axis=1)
df['New Time'] = df['New Time'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(datetime.datetime.timestamp(x)).strftime('%I:%M%p'))
```

output:

```
  Hours Start Time New Time
0  3:30     7:00am  10:30AM
1   1:0     7:00am  08:00AM
2  2:30     7:30am  10:00AM
```

Comment: Question for you, I attempted this with my data set, admittedly I have other rows of data, and my "Start Time" column is the 11th or 12th among them.  I get a error when I try applying your code: `KeyError: ('Start Time', 'occurred at index 0')` any ideas on whats causing it, an issue with the index of the columns? Thanks for you help.

Comment: @SlimJim, do you know the lines it's failing on? Maybe you could add them to the question and i can take a look at it